# Mongoose update a single property if record exists in the array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a user schema looks like this:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  ask_history: [
            {
                user_question_body: {
                    type: String
                },
                favorite: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    default: false
                },
                ask_time: {
                    type: Date,
                    default: Date.now
                }
            }
        ]
})
```

And my current update method looks like this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
        "_id": user_id,
        ask_history.user_question_body: {
            $ne: "an input string"
        }
    }, {
        "$addToSet": {
            ask_history: {
                user_question_body: "an input string"
            }
        }
    }, function(err, doc) {
        if (err)
            throw err; // handle error;
        }
    );
```

How can I add a functionality such that if I ready have a record in ask_history array that has {user_question_body: "an input string"}, then update the {ask_time} to the current update time.

Answer (score 2):

To update `aks_time` of matching document you should use `$` ([positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_))

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
        "_id": user_id,
        "ask_history.user_question_body": "an input string"
    }, {
        "$set": {"ask_history.$.ask_time": new Date()}
    },{new:true, upsert: true}, function(err, doc) {
        if (err)
            throw err; // handle error;
        }
        console.log(doc)
    );
```

Comment: This only update the new date to the existing record that has "ask_history.user_question_body": "an input string", but it doesn't create a record if there isn't one?

Comment: Please add "`upsert`" option with `{new : true}`.E.g : `{new:true,upsert:true}`.